# Show some proofs in $ABCD$, a regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

*My question:*

Let $ABCD$ be a regular tetrahedron and let $O$ be the centre of the base $BCD$.

We consider the points $M \in (AO)$, $N \in (BC)$ and $P \in (BD)$ such that $(MNP) \parallel (ACD)$ and $\frac{OM}{OA} = k$

a) Determine, depending on $k$, the ratio between the area of the triangle $MNP$ and the area of the triangle $ACD$.

b) Determine $k \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the triangle $MNP$ is right-angled.

c) Is there $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the triangle $MNP$ is equilateral?

*The drawing:*

[image]

*My idea*

$(MNP) \parallel (ACD)=>  MN,NP,MP \parallel (ACD)$

Using the theorem:
"If a line $d$ is parallel to a plane $\alpha$ then any other plane $\beta$ that contains this line intersects the initial plane $\alpha$ after a line $g$ that is parallel to the initial line $d$ or with the plane $\alpha$"

We get that $NP \parallel CD$, $MP \parallel AD$
, $MN \parallel AC$.

Using Thales theorem, we get $\frac{CN}{NB}=\frac{PD}{BP}$,also we get that $NPB$ is equilateral

I don't know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Surely you mean that $O$ is the center of the basis $BCD$ ?

Comment: @Digitallis Yeah, that's what the problem says! It means that O is the center of the circumscribed circle.

Comment: But you wrote : Let ABCD
 be a regular tetrahedron and let BCD
 be the center of the base.

Comment: @Digitallis Ooo...sorry!! I edited the misspelling!

Comment: Set it up with coordinates, and it falls out really easily from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E$ be the midpoint of $CD$ and $F$ the midpoint of $NP$. From the similarity of triangles $AOE$ and $MOF$ we get:
$$
{OF\over OE}={OM\over OA}={MF\over AE}=k.
$$
Moreover, from the similarity of $BNP$ and $BCD$ we have:
$$
{PN\over CD}={BF\over BE}={2OE+OF\over 3OE}={2+k\over3}.
$$
Hence:
$$
{area_{MNP}\over area_{ACD}}={PN\cdot MF\over CD\cdot AE}=
{k(2+k)\over3}.
$$
Note then that $\angle NMP=90°$ only if $PN=2MF$, that is:
$$
{2+k\over3}CD=2kAE=k{\sqrt3}\,CD.
$$
This gives the equation $2+k=3k\sqrt3$, with solution:
$$
k={3\sqrt3+1\over13}.
$$
Finally, from $MF={\sqrt3\over2}PN$ we can find the obvious result that $\angle NMP=60°$ if $k=1$.

[image]

Comment: I thought there must be a solution more elegant and exact than mine.  Evidently for me “la diritta via era smarrita.” +1

Comment: @Intellignetipauca Thank you so much for your answer! May I ask how you got to the conclusion that triangles AOE
 and MOF are similar? Thanks again!

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Because in triangle $AOE$ line $MF$ is parallel to $AE$. Hence $\angle AEO=\angle MFO$ and so on.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca excuse me again, but why are these lines parallel?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Because they are the intersections of plane $ABO$ with two parallel planes, $ABC$ and $PMN$. In other words: $AE$ and $MF$ don't have points in common (because they lie on parallel planes) and are coplanar, hence they are parallel (by definition).

Answer (score 0):

Taking the three posted questions in reverse order:

**c)** If plane $PMN$ remains parallel to plane $DAC$ as $M$ moves from $A$ down to $O$, then triangle $PMN$ changes its shape: from equilateral when $M$ coincides with $A$ to degenerate triangle $PMN$ (now a straight line $=\frac{2}{3}\cdot CD$) when $M$ coincides with $O$.

Thus the vertex angle of isosceles $\triangle PMN$ increases from $60^o$ to $180^o$, while the sum of the base angles decreases from $120^o$ to $0^o$. Triangle $PMN$ is **equilateral**, then, only when $M$ coincides with $A$, i.e. when$$\frac{OM}{OA}=k=\frac{1}{1}$$

**b) Approximate solution**: Make $PN\parallel DC$ and such that $PN=OA$, and let the side of the tetrahedron $s=1$. Hence the altitude of the tetrahedron $OA=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}$, and $OE=\frac {1}{3}\cdot BE=\frac{\sqrt 3}{6}$.

Draw $QM\parallel EA$, join $MP$, $MN$, and draw $PR\parallel BE$.

[image: tetrahedron]
Since$$\frac{BE}{DE}=\frac{PR}{DR}=\sqrt 3$$and$$DR=\frac{DC-OA}{2}=\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt3}$$and$$PR=DR\cdot \sqrt 3=\frac{\sqrt 3-\sqrt2}{2}$$then$$OQ=OE-PR=\frac{\sqrt 3}{6}-\frac{\sqrt 3-\sqrt2}{2}=\frac{3\sqrt 2-2\sqrt 3}{6}$$And since$$AE=BE=3\cdot OE$$then by similar triangles$$MQ=3\cdot OQ=\frac{3\sqrt 2-2\sqrt 3}{2}\approx .4$$But$$PQ=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt 3}\approx .4$$Therefore, isosceles triangle $PMN$, in a plane parallel to $\triangle DAC$, has **approximately** a right angle at $M$ when base $PN=OA$.

And since $OM=\sqrt{MQ^2-OQ^2}=\sqrt{(3OQ)^2-OQ^2}$, then in that case$$k=\frac{OM}{OA}=\frac{\sqrt{\left(\frac{3\sqrt 2-2\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3\sqrt 2-2\sqrt 3}{6}\right)^2}}{\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}}=…=\sqrt 6-2$$

**Note**: But again, although $k=\sqrt 6-2$ is exact, $MQ=PQ=.4$ only approximately for $NP=OA=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}$, making $\angle PMN\approx90^o$ when $NP=OA$.

**a)** For all triangles $PMN$ parallel to the plane of $\triangle DAC$, since$$k=\frac{OM}{OA}=\frac{QM}{EA}$$and the areas of triangles are proportional to the ratio of their heights multiplied by the ratio of their bases, then in area$$\frac{\triangle NMP}{\triangle CAD}=k\cdot \frac{NP}{CD}$$